# Change user's number input to a percentage and add that percentage to a specific number

Tags: python, discord.py

**Short version:**  I want to be able to provide a number as an argument in a command, like this, `!info food1 250` the bot then takes the `gatherSpeed` variable and adds the number provided by the user as a percentage.  Like this: `316000( + 250% = number`

**Full Code:**

```
 @info.command(aliases=['Food1', 'f1', 'F1', 'tomato1', 'Tomato1'])
    async def food1(self, ctx, arg: int=0):
        currentDT = DT.datetime.now()
        gatherSpeed = (316000)
        resource = (64300)
        t1 = round((resource) / 108)
        t2 = round((resource) / 124)
        t3 = round((resource) / 142)
        t4 = round((resource) / 164)
        t5 = round((resource) / 188)
        t6 = round((resource) / 217)
        t7 = round((resource) / 249)
        t8 = round((resource) / 287)
        t9 = round((resource) / 330)
        t10 = round((resource) / 379)
        embedResource = discord.Embed(title='Food Tile, Level 1', 
                                    colour=discord.Colour(8596012), 
                                    description=f'Amount of food in tile: **{resource:,}**\nDefault gathering speed: **{gatherSpeed:,}/h**\n\nLevel I troops needed: **{t1:,}**\nLevel II troops needed: **{t2:,}**\nLevel III troops needed: **{t3:,}**\nLevel IV troops needed: **{t4:,}**\nLevel V troops needed: **{t5:,}**\nLevel VI troops needed: **{t6:,}**\n Level VII troops needed: **{t7:,}**\nLevel VIII troops needed: **{t8:,}**\nLevel IX troops needed: **{t9:,}**\nLevel X troops needed: **{t10:,}**', timestamp=currentDT)

        embedResource.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/723743319389110312.png?v=1')
        embedResource.set_image(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/713050313791242322/724817714467569695/image0.png')

        embedResourceArg = discord.Embed(title='Food Tile, Level 1', 
                                        colour=discord.Colour(8596012), 
                                        description=f'Amount of food in tile: **{resource:,}**\nYour gathering speed: **{gatherSpeed + arg + 100:,}/h**\n\nLevel I troops needed: **{t1:,}**\nLevel II troops needed: **{t2:,}**\nLevel III troops needed: **{t3:,}**\nLevel IV troops needed: **{t4:,}**\nLevel V troops needed: **{t5:,}**\nLevel VI troops needed: **{t6:,}**\n Level VII troops needed: **{t7:,}**\nLevel VIII troops needed: **{t8:,}**\nLevel IX troops needed: **{t9:,}**\nLevel X troops needed: **{t10:,}**', timestamp=currentDT)

        embedResourceArg.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/723743319389110312.png?v=1')
        embedResourceArg.set_image(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/713050313791242322/724817714467569695/image0.png')
        if arg != None:
            await ctx.send(embed=embedResourceArg)

        if not arg:
            return await ctx.send(embed=embedResource)
```

**Extended version:** I need a bit of mathematical help with my bot.  I am writing a small bot for a mobile game I play.  You train troops, go to war, gather resources, etc, etc.  There are different levels for the resources, levels 1-8, and each one has a fixed "gathering speed" which can be increased with research or boosts.  I call it "Gathering Boost".

In line 18 is the embed where no gathering boost is applied, and it posts the default gathering speed.  In line 25 is the embed where it should replace the default gathering speed with the total gathering speed, from the gathering boost + the gathering speed.  In this example the gathering speed is 316000.  If I would do `!info food1 250` I want it to say that the gathering speed is `1,106,000`.  Or `316000 + 250% = 1,106,000`.  How do I do that?  `%` is Modulo I found out, and from what I could gather, I'm not able to do something like `{gatherSpeed + arg%:,}`

I know that right now it's `{gatherSpeed + arg + 100:,}`, the `+ 100` was just me testing.

Comment: This would be `gatherSpeed * (1 + arg/100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a percentage, you're really just multiplying by that percentage plus 100, so n + 0% = n * 100%, and n + 50% = n * 150%. To multiply by a percentage, you need to first divide the percentage by 100. so n * 150% = n * 1.5.

To implement this in python you need to write `gatherSpeed * ((arg / 100.0) + 1.0)`, so replace `{gatherSpeed + arg + 100:,}` with `{gatherSpeed * ((arg / 100.0) + 1.0):,}`.

Also, you don't need to put the unmodified version (on line 18) because if `arg` == `0` then this will result in `gatherSpeed * 1.0` = `gatherSpeed`.

Comment: Thank you @BEN1JEN.  That worked!  And also thank you for the tip with line 18, looks much better now :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something like:
`gatherSpeed + gatherSpeed*2.5`